# Finding MSBuild using vswhere in invoke-build on an ADO pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, invoke-build

On my local machine I can use MSBuild pretty easily. But when I try to use the same PowerShell script as I do on my local machine on an ADO Pipeline, I get complaints that MSBuild is a not a cmdlet. This leads me to believe that I need to use vswhere to find MSBuild on the agent machine and then use that to build my slns. I've looked around on the web without any luck, so I thought I'd ask here just in case anyone has dealt with something like this before.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the "Invoke-build" powershell module and that is how you are calling your scripts in your ADO pipeline (i.e. you are running Invoke-Build from powershell in a directory with a *.build.ps1 script containing the tasks that call your build scripts)

If so it comes with a built-in helper command called "Resolve-MSBuild" which does exactly what you want.

If you add the statement:

```
Set-Alias MSBuild (Resolve-MSBuild)
```

at the top of your .build.ps1 script (prior to any task statements) this should create a command alias that will run the actual msbuild whenever called.